# SAP/ERP export file format?

Tags: xml, sap-erp

Do we have some SAP/ERP expert here?

I need to know what format SAP or other ERPs export their information to.

Eg. product information, travelling information etc.

Is it XML or could they export to other formats?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, i think.

What do you mean by "export their file to" ? speaking of SAP, nearly all data are stored into a database, whose structure is quite complex. Depending on the domain, domain-specific application export some data onto a variety of format, and specific applications can be made to export to a given format if none exist. PDF, Excel, Word, CSV and others are available to developpers.

If the need is to move from one system to another, then you ***will*** need to code.

regards,
Guillaume

Comment: But if I have an external application that could use the information about their products, travels and so on, what is the best way for them to provide this for me? Is it to export their database product information into XML so that I could import the product or travel information into my database? Could I tell them that I need it to be in this XML structure and provide all the XML elements and attributes for them. Could they convert their information into MY XML structure? Or is there a best practice for this?

Comment: If you can provide an XML format, and the information exist in the SAP system, then your ABAPers can develop an application to produce this file. We do this quite commonly in HR to export informations to others applications.
Reading *directly* the database is a no-no in SAP world. 
Regards